# Using JQuery in ReactJS Events

Tags: reactjs, reactive-programming

Hot to use Jquery for example in onChange event
Example

```
change(){
$('#selector').trigger('event')..... 
}

render() {
  return <select onChange={this.change}>
             <option value="1>" 1  </option> ..... 

}
```

Comment: No need for any jQuery: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: you can do  this action in two way

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: don't.

You make a class and then pass the function to the handler. For example:

```
class Blah extends React.Component {
  handleClick = e => alert('Button click');
  render() {
    return (<button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me.</button>);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In React you can do  this action in two way

- using react setState
- use jquery in after component is mounted.

i would prefer to do react way, advantage of using it you are not touching the Dom. Remember everytime you touch the DOM, it is expensive.